# ACR Service Principal

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to create a Service Principal for my Container Registry, however, I was given a user with type Guest and on the AZ CLI I keep getting: Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write over the resource. Are there some privileges my user needs?

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can accept it. Or for more help please show me the message.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, you should check the required permission of your role follow [Create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).

If you have the User role, you must make sure that non-administrators can register applications. Or you are the global administrators.